# How to Center a Map on User Location IOS 9 SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Hi I have the below code which is finding the user location the radius within 1 mile:

```
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 51.5001524, longitude: -0.1262362)
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func centerMapOnLocation(location:CLLocation) {
        let coordianteRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
            regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordianteRegion, animated: true)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      centerMapOnLocation(initialLocation)

        }

This is perfect as gets a decent radius for user location, however i want to know, how do you center map on user location?
```

i have tried a lot of methods but i do not seem to be able to get the map to center on user location.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`MKMapView` has a built in solution by using the `userTrackingMode` property.

```
mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this might help you

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    let location = locations.last as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```